# How does {{ $t(...) }} in Shopware 6 admin twig files work in detail?

Tags: shopware6

I am going through the [swag bundle example](https://github.com/shopware/swag-docs-bundle-example/blob/63ffbb2c513713d92ee3fb9b7f84a6aa8be90112/src/Resources/app/administration/src/module/swag-bundle/page/swag-bundle-list/swag-bundle-list.html.twig#L6) which has code like

```
<sw-button variant="primary" :routerLink="{ name: 'swag.bundle.create' }">
    {{ $t('swag-bundle.list.addButtonText') }}
</sw-button>
```

I understand that the twig code `{{ ... }}` and so on is processed by the server and then the Vue components `<sw-button>` by Vue itself.

Now the `swag-bundle.list.addButtonText` is in the snippet file which seems to be processed client side.

Does the evaluation of the translation directive `$t('swag-bundle.list.addButtonText')` happen server side or in JavaScript?

Or both?

Related: In the https://academy.shopware.com/courses/take/shopware-6-developer-training-advanced-en/ `$tc` seems to be used - what is the difference between `$tc` and `$t`?

Answer (score 4):

Both function are from [Vue I18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/).

`$t` is for normal [translations](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/formatting.html#named-formatting) and `$tc` is used for [pluralization](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/pluralization.html#accessing-the-number-via-the-pre-defined-argument)

Comment: As for the first part: I am just confused because I thought the evaluation of `{{ }}` happens server side.

Comment: No vue.js uses the same for it's templates: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#text-interpolation